# Use jqPlot with Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, jqplot

I want to create a bar chart in a system which is based on zend framework, I found this jqPlot as a good way to do that. But I can not understand how to map this with MVC layout and again how can I use an array to pass the data extracted from zend model to the javascript function in zend view? I tried so many ways but could not get the required result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AJAX data renderer](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/data-renderers.php) for jqPlot. Then you should generate data in your logic/model class and fetch it by retrieving data from controller action.

### Example:

### view

```
<div id="sharechart"></div>
```

### layout

(don't forget to include scripts required by jqPlot)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxShare = function() {
    var data = null;                
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: '<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/charts/getshare',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            data = response;
        },
    });

    return data;
};

$.jqplot('sharechart', {
    title: '<h1>Bank share</h1>',
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            showDataLabels: true,
            dataLabels: 'label',
        }
    },
    legend: { show:true, location: 'e' },
    dataRenderer: ajaxShare,
});
</script>
```

### controller

```
public function getshareAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    $logic = new My_Charts();

    $shareArray = $logic->getShareData();

    echo json_encode(array($shareArray));
}
```